# Adding every 60th value in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I want to calculate the sum of the the 1st 60 element, the 2nd 60 element and so on in a column. The code what I wrote so far doesn't work:

```
Function sixtysum(data)
    Dim xa()
    For i = 1 To 5475 Step 60
        For j = i To i + 60
            xa(j) = 0
            xa(j) = xa(j) + data(j)
        Next j
    Next i
    sixtysum = xa()
End Function
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the `data` argument that you're passing in?

Comment: Daily log returns of a stock.

Comment: More information needed. What does the data look like?  HOW does it "doesn't work"?

Comment: This function requires an argument (`data`) of unknown type, and then does nothing with this argument within the function body. Your function body is essentially a null program at this point. Is `data` a range/column of cells? If not, what is it, and what do you intend to do with it?

Comment: Yes, it is a column of cells. I want to sum the first 60 element of this column. Then the second 60 element, so the output should be a column with  5475/60 cells.

Comment: Generally speaking it is not possible to use a worksheet `Function` to manipulate worksheet objects. So you cannot output a "column" of multiple cells -- because functions cannot do this. They can ordinarily only return a value to the cell where the function is called.

Comment: Is `data` an array or a `Range`?

Comment: It is a range. An I want this function to return an array.

Answer (score 1):

Use function to return array in memory to other function/subroutines.  **Untested**

```
Function f_sixtysum(data as Range) As Variant
    Dim i as Long, x as Integer
    Dim startRng as Range, endRng as Range
    Dim mySum as Double
    Dim var as Variant

    If data Is Nothing then GoTo EarlyExit

    '## Make sure your array is properly sized, this is a one-dimensional array with n/60 elements.
    ReDim var(Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundUp((data.Rows.Count/60) - 1,0)

    '## Make sure the range we're working with only the FIRST column
    Set data = data.Resize(data.Rows.Count, 1) 

    '## Iterate over the range in increment of 60
    For i = 1 to data.Cells.Count step 60
        '## Compute the sum of 60 cells and store in the temporary array "var"
        var(x)  = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum( _
                           Range(data(i), Range(data(i+59)))
        '## increment our array counter variable
        x = x + 1
    Next

    '## Assign our temporary array "var" to the function's return value
    f_sixtysum = var

    Exit Function
EarlyExit:
    'Returns an empty array
    f_sixtysum = Array()

End Sub
```